# pulling data from mysql in app open only in browser

Tags: mysql, webrick

When I open a backbone app, which uses mysql,  in Firefox, this is the url of the index.

```
file:///Users/mm/Sites/ccoenraets/web/index.html#
```

In the app itself, this is the  url where it's supposed to retrieve the data from

```
 urlRoot:"../api/employees",
```

When I play around with the app in Firefox, it's not pulling data from the database. Do you know how I should change that urlRoot to make it get the data from the database. I tried the obvious without success

```
 urlRoot:"Users/mm/Sites/ccoenraets/web/index/api/employees",
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code that is supposed to handle the `api/employees` URL, but in any case it will need to run on a webserver and not just have it loaded by your browser as a local file.

Comment: ok, thanks. This is just a javascript app. I use webrick for Rails. do you know how I can get it running on a webserver if I'm not in the Rails environment?

Comment: Can't help you with Rails, but I've retagged your question, so now it should be more visible to Rails people.

Comment: @ianzz sorry, miscommunication. It's NOT a Rails environment, so what webserver would you use?

Comment: I had to google WEBrick just to find out that it is actually a webserver implemented in Ruby. You _are_ going to do better if you're getting help with setting it up from Ruby/Rails people than from me.

Comment: I got a webserver installed (static for Node js) and the app's running at localhost:8080. However, it's still not getting data from database. do i have to do anything special do you know?

Comment: You need to request your site through `http://localhost:8080` URLs, not through `file://...` URLs, _or_ use absolute URLs to `http://localhost:8080` in your HTML and Javascript.